# CakePHP 3 : How to prepare cakephp table paginate header for localization?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

My table header look below

```
<th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('name')?></th>
```

After generate POT file 'name' has not generate 'msgid' and 'msgstr'.

I have tried like below code but result is same.

```
<th scope="col"><?= __($this->Paginator->sort('name')) ?></th>
```

How I will prepare it before POT file generate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your label like

```
<th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('name',__('Name')) ?></th>
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the key in sort function is used to sort the recordset. You cannot use it to generate 'msgid' and 'msgstr' in your POT file.

You can generate msgid and msgstr simply by defining it elsewhere like

```
<? = __('name') ?>;

PaginatorHelper::sort($key, $title = null, $options = array())
```

For your reference:
https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html